# Regarding extstrings

Tags: extjs

Iam looking for extstrings for portugese and spanish. Can you plase let me know where can i find those files. I have treid to search in the ext 3.0.3 downloaded files but i did not find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded ext 3.1.1 and I've found the file you are looking for under :

- **src\locale\ext-lang-pt.js** for portugese
- **src\locale\ext-lang-es.js** for spanish